# removing file names from a list python

Tags: python

I have all filenames of a directory in a list named files. And I want to filter it so only the files with the .php extension remain.

```
for x in files:
    if x.find(".php") == -1:
        files.remove(x)
```

But this seems to skip filenames. What can I do about this?

Comment: You're modifying the list that you're iterating over. This is generally a bad idea (and is the cause of it "skipping filenames").

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about a simple list comprehension?

```
files = [f for f in files if f.endswith('.php')]
```

Or if you prefer a generator as a result:

```
files = (f for f in files if f.endswith('.php'))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> files = ['a.php', 'b.txt', 'c.html', 'd.php']
>>> [f for f in files if f.endswith('.php')]
['a.php', 'd.php']
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers provided give list / generator comprehensions, which are probably the way you want to go 90% of the time, especially if you don't want to modify the original list.

However, for those situations where (say for size reasons) you want to modify the original list in place, I generally use the following snippet:

```
idx = 0
while idx < len(files):
    if files[idx].find(".php") == -1:
        del files[idx]
    else:
        idx += 1
```

As to why your original code wasn't working - it's changing the list as you iterator over it... the "for x in files" is implicitly creating an iterator, just like if you'd done "for x in iter(files)", and deleting elements in the list confuses the iterator about what position it is at. For such situations, I generally use the above code, or if it happens a lot in a project, factor it out into a function, eg:

```
def filter_in_place(func, target):
    idx = 0
    while idx < len(target):
        if func(target[idx)):
            idx += 1
        else:
            del target[idx]
```

Comment: Good point, this might come in handy with very large lists or in low-end systems.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across this old question. Many solutions here will do the job but they ignore a case where filename could be just ".php". I suspect that the question was about how to filter PHP scripts and ".php" may not be a php script. Solution that I propose is as follows:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> files = ['a.php', 'b.txt', 'c.html', 'd.php', '.php']
>>> [f for f in files if os.path.splitext(f)[1] == ".php"]
```